# MySQL: Which join is better between left outer join and inner join

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-performance

Which join is better peforming if all of them provides the same result?
For example, I have a two tables `employees(emp_id,name, address, designation, age, sex)` and `work_log(emp_id,date,hours_wored)`. To get some specific results both `inner join` and `left join` gives the same result. But, I have still some doubts which is not limited to this question only.

- which join is more efficient which should prefer in case of same result values ?
- What are other factors which must be considered at the time of applying join?
- Is there any relationship between inner join and cross join?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is not a "better" or a "worse" join type. They have different meaning and they must be used depending on it.

In your case, you probably do not have employees with no `work_log` (no rows in that table), so `LEFT JOIN` and `JOIN` will be equivalent in results. However, if you had such a thing (a new employee with no registered `work_log`), a `JOIN` wold omit that employee, while a left join (whose first table is employees) would show all of them, and nulls on the fields from `work_log` if there are not matches.

[image: Visual explanation of JOIN types]
*Image by C.L. Moffatt on [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)*

Again, performance is a secondary thing to query correctness. Some people say that you shouldn't use `LEFT JOIN`s. It is true that a `LEFT JOIN` forces the optimizer to execute the query in one particular order, preventing some optimizations (table reordering) in some cases. [Here is one example](http://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/2c1o1c/are_significantly_fewer_records_better_even_if/cjbmdg2). But you should not choose one over the other if correctness/meaning is sacrificed, as an `INNER JOIN` is not inherently worse. The rest of the usual optimizations apply as usual.

In summary, do not use `LEFT JOIN` if you really mean `INNER JOIN`.

In MySQL `CROSS JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` are the same. In the standard, and semantically, a `CROSS JOIN` is an `INNER JOIN` without an `ON` clause, so you get every combination of rows between tables.

You have [examples of all semantic types of join on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). In practice, in MySQL, we tend to only write `JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: And for the sake of completeness: [In MySQL writing `JOIN` unqualified implies `INNER JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418849/345716)

Answer (score 2):

*Which join is better performing if all of them provides the same result?*

I addition of the previous answer, for what I know, MySQL is optimized to have the same performance.

With good indexes, for example, `JOIN` vs `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE` clause to filter, will be the same thing. *Optimization* vs *Human Reading* take sense on large queries with lot of joins.

Using good indexes and cache is more important.

You can read a good explanation of the optimization process here :

[The Query Optimization Process](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9780596101718/ch04.html) : *A query can often be executed many different ways and produce the same result. The optimizer’s job is to find the best option.*

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same for me, MySql 5.7 8 vCPU, 52 GB RAM

The following query takes ~30 seconds, not sure why

The transactions table has 24,257,151 records

The activity table has 18,603,665 records

The purchases table has 13,911,705 records

All required indexes are in place

```
SELECT
    `trx`.`transaction_pk`,
    `trx`.`created`,
    `trx`.`updated`,
    `p`.`amount`,
    `trxst`.`name`,
    COALESCE ( a.units, 0 ) AS units
FROM
    `transaction` AS `trx`
    INNER JOIN `transaction_sub_type` AS `trxst` ON  `trx`.`transaction_sub_type_fk`= `trxst`.`transaction_sub_type_pk`
    left JOIN `activity` AS `a` ON `a`.`transaction_fk` = `trx`.`transaction_pk`
    LEFT JOIN `purchases` AS `p` ON `p`.`transaction_fk` = `trx`.`transaction_pk` 
WHERE
    `trx`.`entity_fk` IN ( 1234) 
    AND `trx`.`transaction_sub_type_fk` IN (
    2, 4, 5, 15, 16, 33, 37, 38, 85, 86, 87, 88, 102, 103 
    ) 
ORDER BY
    `trx`.`transaction_pk` DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0;
```

After replacing the following line:

```
INNER JOIN `transaction_sub_type` AS `trxst` ON  `trx`.`transaction_sub_type_fk`= `trxst`.`transaction_sub_type_pk`
```

with LEFT JOIN

```
LEFT JOIN `transaction_sub_type` AS `trxst` ON  `trx`.`transaction_sub_type_fk`= `trxst`.`transaction_sub_type_pk`
```

the same query takes ~0.046s

Explain before:

```
1   SIMPLE  trxst       ALL PRIMARY             101 37.62   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  trx     ref transaction_sub_type_fk,entity_fk   transaction_sub_type_fk 4   trxst.transaction_sub_type_pk   2548    0.36    Using where
1   SIMPLE  a       ref transaction_fk  transaction_fk  4   trx.transaction_pk  1   100 
1   SIMPLE  p       ref transaction_fk  transaction_fk  4   trx.transaction_pk  1   100
```

Explain after:

```
1   SIMPLE  trx     ref transaction_sub_type_fk,entity_fk   entity_fk   4   const   81474   83.65   Using where
1   SIMPLE  trxst       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   trx.transaction_sub_type_fk 1   100 
1   SIMPLE  a       ref transaction_fk  transaction_fk  4   trx.transaction_pk  1   100 
1   SIMPLE  p       ref transaction_fk  transaction_fk  4   trx.transaction_pk  1   100
```

Comment: You'd need to remove the LIMIT to get to a meaningful performance comparison.